# Nucleo F446ZE VS Nucleo F446RE

Tags: programming, platformio

I don't know if this is the right forum to ask this, but I can't find people that want to help, so let's try it here...

First I had an F446RE, and program it in PlatformIO with an Arduino Framework...

Now I have a Nucleo F446ZE and want to program it, but in PlatformIO I can't choose Arduino Framework.

Can I change that? or  what else to use?
CMSIS
Nbed
STM32Cube
libopencm3
Zephyr RTOS

thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, STM32duino (STM32 Arduino Core) supports F446RE, but not F446ZE yet. Depend on your skill, STM32 Arduino Core wiki has description on how to create your own custom board, but it is not for beginner. For non-Arduino, I would suggest to use STM32CubeIDE.

Comment: And who put them in the STM32 arduimo Core?

Comment: As an open source project, anyone can help out to create the variant and submit a pull request to add the variant via STM32duino github, in fact ST maintain a long list of boards that they hope someone could help to [add the variant](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/issues/722) for supporting various boards.